# How to transfer edge directions from one networkx graph object to another?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, networkx

Let's say I have a pandas dataframe of the form **df**

```
Source  Target  Weight   Type
  A       B       0.4    Directed
  B       A       0.2    Directed
  A       C       0.5    Directed
  C       A       0.5    Directed
  ..
```

I get a directed graph object from this dataframe using networkx called **G1**.

I also have a dataframe **df2** of the form,

```
Source  Target  Weight   Type
  A       B       0.4    Undirected
  A       C       0.1    Undirected
  ..
```

I get an undirected graph from this dataframe called **G2**. As you can see, unlie G1, this is undirected.

I want to know how I can transfer the directions from G1 to G2. This can be done either at the pandas stage or the graph object stage. The following is the basic logic in interpreting directionality in G1 (note that edges exist both ways from A-B and B-A, likewise for A-C and C-A). For a given pair (assume AB) we take the direction for which the value of the weight is higher. In our example, we retain AB as the resultant direction since its weight is greater than BA. In the case of a tie we may take either of the values (for instance CA). Finally, these directions need to be applied to G2. So now AB in G2 is a directed source-target pair and so is CA.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

From the dataframe of directed graphs create a column of directions

```
df['vertices'] = np.sort(df.values[:,:2],axis=1).sum(1)
```

Now you can sort the dataframe by `Weight` and keep every first duplicate direction (The largest distance value)

```
df.sort_values('Weight',ascending=False).drop_duplicates('vertices',keep='first')



 Source Target  Weight      Type vertices
2      A      C     0.5  Directed       AC
0      A      B     0.4  Directed       AB
```

Comment: Sure, I want to 'transfer' these directions onto the second dataframe. How do I do that?

Comment: I don’t really know what you mean by *“transfer”*. Can you elaborate? Maybe add your expected output to your question